# Is calling a function only twice a good use of recursion?

Tags: perl, subroutine

Is this, technically, a recursive function? It only gets called once by itself, but it cleaned up my code quite a bit, I think.  Or, does it needlessly complicate the code?

```
sub check_backlog {
    my $topic        = shift;
    my $prev_backlog = shift;
    my $backlog      = undef;
    my @status = `$CMD -topicstat $topic`;
    foreach (@status) {
        if (/Message count: (\d+)/) {
            $backlog = $LAST_PAREN_MATCH;
            if ( !$prev_backlog && $backlog > 1 ) {
                sleep $topic_wait_time;
                check_backlog( $topic, $backlog );
            }
            elsif ( $backlog > $prev_backlog ) {
                check_over_thresholds($backlog);
            }
        }
    }
    return $backlog;
}
```

Comment: Could you describe the intent of the code as well? I don't know enough PERL to entirely understand what you are actually doing, so I can't tell whether recursion is considered a good solution here.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris The intent is to query a queue, to determine if it is not moving data through it.  This was written in perl because the queue is a vendor supplied JMS queue.

Comment: To see whether data is moving through, can't you just check the head element and see whether it changes over time? If I interpret that correctly, recursion isn't a good solution IMHO.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris - As for checking the head element, I don't know how I'd do that, outside of running this as Java instead. Again, it's not my code administering the queue. Any code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer with pseudo code with what I believe would be the proper solution for how I understand the intent of this code at the moment. To get help on how to achieve this in PERL, you probably have more luck on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what is actually happening here. I have no idea what `$CMD -topicstat $topic` returns. I can tell you that making it recursive was a mistake. If you posted the code you had before cleaning it up, then I could help you clean it up better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every function which calls itself is considered a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

Recursion is really useful when traversing trees and such.

As I don't fully understand Perl, I can't really tell whether this case is proper use of recursion, perhaps also provide the intent of your code.

UPDATE

If you simply want to see whether data is passing (or not passing) through a queue, I wouldn't find recursion to be a suitable implemention.

I would expect a function which returns either `true` or `false` after a given amount of time, or immediately when data is passing through.

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
function isDataPassing( queue, time )
{
   headOfQueue = queue.peek();
   dataPassing = false;
   while ( timePassed < time )
   {
       if ( headOfQueue != queue.peek() )
       {
           dataPassing = true;
           break;
       }
   }

   return dataPassing;
}
```

I can't help you with how you would go about implementing this in Perl. StackOverflow is a better location to ask such a question.

Comment: It's Perl not PERL.

Comment: In Perl instead of setting a variable in the loop, and later returning it; you would just write `return 1;` ( `1` being a true value )

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Perl well enough, but this looks suspicious to me. On the one hand, you return a value from `check_backlog` with:

```
return $backlog;
```

But when calling `check_backlog` you don't use the return value at all!

```
check_backlog( $topic, $backlog );
```

The only result of the recursive call is that it may `sleep` some time, but it will not affect returned value.

But again, I know only a little Perl, so I might be wrong.

Comment: The code should flow like this: call #1 - get any count of backlog, call #2 - see that it's been called before, then check if the number of messages queued has grown. If it has, call the threshold check function.

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  When it does return the $backlog var, it will return the first result, not the second, as it probably should?